# How can I edit the code such that it returns a message when there is no invoice found otherwise it should display it when its there

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I edit the code such that it returns a message when there is no invoice found? Otherwise, it should display it when it's there.

Here is what I have:

```js
<template v-if="isInvoice">
  <v-card-text
    class="elevation-1 mb-1"
    v-for="i in pageCount(invoice)"
    :key="i"
  >
    <pdf
      style="width: 100%"
      :src="`data:application/pdf;base64,${invoice}`"
      :page="i"
    >
  </v-card-text>
</template>

<v-card-text v-else>
  <v-skeleton-loader
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="500"
    type="image, article"
  />
  <span>Please wait....</span>
</v-card-text>

<script>
  computed: {
    invoice() {
      return this.$store.getters["Billing/invoice"];
    },
    isInvoice() {
      return this.invoice || this.invoice !== "";
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think it should work if you just exchange the || in isInvoice with && or you could just remove the second part because an empty string is falsy.

Comment: @timmmmmb how  can I edit the above code such that when there's an empty string i get "No invoice found" instead of ""

Comment: You could probably check inside of invoice if the getter is empty. 
You could replace the computed invoice with: 
invoice() {
let invoice = this.$store.getters["Billing/invoice"];
return invoice ? invoice : 'No invoice found';
}
but you would now need to check if it is still loading inside of isInvoice

Comment: okay, lemme try that i will get back to you

Comment: `this.invoice !== ""` part in isInvoice() doesn't seem right, please remove that and try